# Is it possible to show/hide fields in the KeystoneJS 5 AdminUI?

Tags: keystonejs

Basically what the title says -- we are working on a project where we'd like to be able to show and hide various fields based on the value of other fields. This seems to have been [possible in KeystoneJS 4](https://v4.keystonejs.com/api/field/options/) but I see no mention of it in KeystoneJS 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dependsOn` feature of keystoneJs v4 has not made it to latest KeystoneJs iteration. v5 (as we call it) is complete rewrite and does not have many features from v4.

however there is a [Pull Request](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/pull/2260) which may add this feature but unfortunately that is not the priority for the core team and they have not responded on the PR.

once that PR is merged you can do something like this

```js
keystone.createList('Test field', {
  fields: {
    price: { type: Decimal, symbol: '$' },
    currency: { type: Text, dependsOn: { $lt: { price: 3 } } },
    hero: { type: File, adapter: fileAdapter, dependsOn: { $gt: { price: 3 } } },
    markdownValue: { type: Markdown, dependsOn: { $gt: { price: 6 } } },
    fortyTwo: {
      type: Virtual,
      graphQLReturnType: `Int`,
      resolver: () => 42,
    },
  }});
```